# How to solve ghosting issue of NSWindow without any styleMask?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

In my project I want a NSWindow without any styleMask, therefor I am using this code:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    private lazy var window: NSWindow = NSWindow()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        window.styleMask = [] // [.titled]
        window.backingType = .buffered
        window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
        window.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 0.2)
        window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
        
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: ContentView())
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        
    }

}
--------------------------------------------------------
let nsApplication: NSApplication = NSApplication.shared
let appDelegate: AppDelegate = AppDelegate()
nsApplication.delegate = appDelegate
nsApplication.run()
```

---

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var size: CGFloat = 300.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Circle()
                .frame(width: size, height: size)
                .onTapGesture { size = 150.0 }
                .animation(.default, value: size)

        }
        .frame(width: 500.0, height: 500.0)
    }
}
```

The issue of no styleMask is ghosting like this:

[image]

But if we use `window.styleMask = [.titled]` there would be no ghosting issue, so How I can keep using no styleMask like `window.styleMask = []` and solving the ghosting issue?